# How to easily create JsonReader only for case classes in Spray Json?

Tags: spray-json

Is it possible to easily create a JsonReader only (not a JsonFormat!) for a case class in Spray easily?

For reading and writing there is:
`implicit val xyzFormat = jsonFormatN(Xyz)`

But it picks up JsonFormats for nested types, if a nested type uses a custom serialization you have always write a Format with read() and write() then, which is cumbersome, if you only want to support read or write.

Comment: I've wanted this too. Likely the answer is "no" but based on how the 'jsonFormatN' are defined, we could probably implement this easily.